# Displaying CSV file as HTML page using Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, tablib

I have a CSV file called random.csv which I want to render on a html page if the user is logged in. I've tried using tablib for this.

`__init__.py`

```py
    from flask import Flask
    import tablib

    app = Flask(__name__)
    dataset = tablib.Dataset()
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'random.csv')) as f:
    dataset.csv = f.read()

routes.py

    @app.route('/dataset', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    @login_required
    def dataset():
        return dataset.html
```

This is the index.html file from where I want to link to the html page for the csv file.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <p><a href="{{ url_for('dataset') }}">Click to see CSV</a> </p>
{% endblock %}
```

And this is the dataset.html file where I want to see the CSV data.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}
```

I'm getting this error:
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'html'
The error is on the line in routes.py file where I return the dataset.html file.

Comment: use `pandas`. `df = pandas.read_csv('random.csv')` and the `table = df.to_html()`

Comment: I have to use just Flask actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using pandas instead tablib. In my routes.py file just did this:

```
import pandas as pd

@app.route('/dataset', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def dataset():
    table = pd.read_csv('filepath', encoding= 'unicode_escape')
    return render_template("dataset.html", data=table.to_html())
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you shadowed whatever the variable was with the function name:

```
    def dataset():
        return dataset.html
```

`dataset` is the function. If it was something else before, naming your function `dataset` replaced whatever that variable was.